# JMVTI:Could not find agent library

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

I wrote an agent for Java which does nothing just exports two methods, just to check if it loaded on JVM start or not. Built it with mingw-w64 4.8.4 (using JetBrains CLion). Windows 7 x64.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, char *options, void *reserved){
  return JNI_OK;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Agent_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm){}
```

Got an error running

```
java -agentlib:"C:\JMVAgent\agent.dll"

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library libSampleAgent.dll on the library path, 
with error: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Also I placed agent.dll into c:\windows\System32 and run java w/o agent full path with the same result.

DependencyWalker shows no dependency error
[image]

Please help to find what I'm doing wrong

Comment: How did you compile .dll? Note, if you are specifying full path to the agent library, use `-agentpath` instead of `-agentlib`.

Comment: I don't understand your question regard compiling, what exactly are you interested in? -agentpath helps, thanks a lot!

Comment: I mean the command line, how did you build .dll from the source. But never mind. Since `agentpath` solves the problem, I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you with to specify the full path to the agent library, use `-agentpath` instead of `-agentlib`.

The difference is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#starting).